# How to add multiple key-value pair to Dictionary at once?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary `my_dict` having some elements like:

```py
my_dict = {
    'India':'Delhi',
    'Canada':'Ottawa',
}
```

Now I want to add multiple dictionary key-value pair to a `dict` like:

```py
my_dict = {
    'India': 'Delhi',
    'Canada': 'Ottawa',
    'USA': 'Washington',
    'Brazil': 'Brasilia',
    'Australia': 'Canberra',
}
```

Is there any possible way to do this?
Because I don't want to add elements one after the another.

Comment: `dict.update({'India': 'Delhi', 'Canada': 'Ottawa'})`

Answer (score 23):

Use `update()` method.

```
d= {'India':'Delhi','Canada':'Ottawa'}
d.update({'USA':'Washington','Brazil':'Brasilia','Australia':'Canberra'})
```

PS: Naming your dictionary as `dict` is a horrible idea. It replaces the built in `dict`.

Answer (score 3):

To make things more interesting in this answer section, you can

> add multiple dictionary key-value pair to a dict

by doing so (In Python 3.5 or greater):

```
d = {'India': 'Delhi', 'Canada': 'Ottawa'}
d = {**d, 'USA': 'Washington', 'Brazil': 'Brasilia', 'Australia': 'Canberra', 'India': 'Blaa'}
```

Which produces an output:

```
{'India': 'Blaa', 'Canada': 'Ottawa', 'USA': 'Washington', 'Brazil': 'Brasilia', 'Australia': 'Canberra'}
```

This alternative doesn't even seem memory inefficient. Which kind-a comes as a contradiction to one of "The Zen of Python" postulates,

> [There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

What I didn't like about the *d.update()* alternative are the round brackets, when I skim read and see round brackets, I usually think tuples.
Either way, added this answer just to have some fun.

Answer (score 1):

you have a few options:

1. use `update()`:

```
d= {'India':'Delhi','Canada':'Ottawa'}
d.update({'USA':'Washington','Brazil':'Brasilia','Australia':'Canberra'})
```

2. use `merge`:

```
d= {'India':'Delhi','Canada':'Ottawa'}
d2 = {'USA':'Washington','Brazil':'Brasilia','Australia':'Canberra'}
new_dict = d| d2
```

Answer (score 0):

The update() method works well

As someone who primarily works in pandas data frames, I wanted to share how you can take values from a data frame and add them to a dictionary using update() and pd.to_dict().

```
import pandas as pd
```

Existing dictionary

```
my_dict = {
        'India':'Delhi',
        'Canada':'Ottawa',
    }
```

Data frame with additional values you want to add to dictionary

```
country_index = ['USA','Brazil','Australia']
city_column = ['Washingon','Brasilia','Canberra']
new_values_df = pd.DataFrame(data=city_column, index=country_index, columns=['cities'])
```

Adding data frame values to dictionary

```
my_dict.update(new_values_df.to_dict(orient='dict')['cities'])
```

Dictionary now looks like

```
my_dict = {
    'India': 'Delhi',
    'Canada': 'Ottawa',
    'USA': 'Washington',
    'Brazil': 'Brasilia',
    'Australia': 'Canberra',
}
```